# React useState: preserve state between instances of an element factory

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a hook for showing errors. Below is the simplified solution.

The `useError` function takes a factory for elements given errors and returns a proper React element factory for rendering.

My problem is that `useError` creates a new factory each time it's called, which it needs to because it closes over the current errors. But this results in ErrorsDisplay being mounted on each error added and thus it's state reset (can be seen in the sample, when you click the app to add an error).

```
const useErrors = factory => {
  let [error, setError] = useState([]);

  const addError = e => setError(s => [...s, e]);

  return [props => factory(error), addError];
};

const ErrorDisplay = props => {
  let [someState, setSomeState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => setSomeState(s => s + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [someState]);

  return (
    <div>
      {someState} + {props.errors.length}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  let [Error, add] = useErrors(errors => <ErrorDisplay errors={errors} />);

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={() => add("my error")}>
      <Error />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For a playground see https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-star-k529l.

My only "solution" so far is to keep the instance of the errors array in `useError` and push new errors onto it (and then force a rerender by setting some other state too) ala:

```
const useErrors = factory => {
  let [error] = useState([]);
  let [token, render] = useState(true);

  const addError = e => {
       error.push(e);
       render(!token)
  }

  return [useCallback((props) => factory(error), []), addError];
};
```

I don't find the very idiomatic and I don't know if this gives me any other issues down the line.

My question is: Is there a way to make this work without mutable state, preferably with the same api for `useError` or something along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution here is to not return a component from useError but just the data value and render your component directly

```
const useErrors = factory => {
  let [error, setError] = useState([]);

  const addError = e => setError(s => [...s, e]);

  return [error, addError];
};

const ErrorDisplay = props => {
  let [someState, setSomeState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout = setTimeout(() => setSomeState(s => s + 1), 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [someState]);

  return (
    <div>
      {someState} + {props.errors.length}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  let [errors, add] = useErrors();

  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={() => add("my error")}>
      <ErrorDisplay errors={errors} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-noether-jpqc0?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hmm... yeah, I'm afraid you're right. Afraid because that's almost to obvious and I'm ashamed I didn't think of it :D
I kind of wish I had expanded my sample though, as I have another use case where it would be very nice to be able to provide a factory and return a wrapped factory. It might be though, that I try to bend hooks to much...

Comment: I'll post another question for that one :)

Comment: Hooks are very much dependent on closures and hence cause a lot of debugging headaches sometimes